# Variable Table Name in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, vba

I've looked through the forums and know this question has been asked before, but even after trying what has been suggested I still can't get this to work. I'm fairly new to both VBA and SQL so that could explain why I'm struggling.

What I'm trying to do is create a Form that when executed runs this query:

```
strSQL = "SELECT new.[Service Name], new.WBS, new.[Billing Code], new.[CPU Units], new.[VCPU Units], new.[Billing Status], new.[Bill To] " & _
 " FROM " & strNew & " AS new LEFT JOIN " & strOld & " AS old ON new.[Service Name] = old.[Service Name] " & _
 " WHERE old.[Service Name] Is Null;"
```

I created the form and have stored the user inputs into both strNew and strOld respectively. However when I execute this code, I receive an error. I've confirmed the values inputted into the form are actual "tables" that are located in the database. Why does this not work? I appreciate the help.

Comment: Can you list the error?

Comment: Try putting blank space before "FROM" and "WHERE".   If that doesn't work, edit your post and tell us what error message you are getting.

Comment: What error? How are you executing the SQL string?

Comment: If you have multiple tables with exactly the same columns (i.e. it won't cause any errors to chop and change the table names in this query) then this is a bit of a code smell. Could you not have a single table, then use a column as an identifier where you are currently using a new table? Also consider not putting spaces and other special characters in object names, it is very annoying for anyone who has to query your database!

Comment: Urm, what? Unless I am really misreading, are you trying to do a `left join on` t1.a = t2.a, `where` t2.a is `null`? You should be aware that under ANSI (read: sane) rules, nothing is equal to a `null` - not even another `null`. So even if you fix the syntax of the query, its sense will still be way off. And even if you worked under relaxed (read: bad) rules regarding comparing `nulls`, the `join` would be pointless; you would (for whatever unclear reason) simply need to do a `where` on each table.column `is null`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are trying to create a dynamic query, the first advise i can give you, you need to read this [Erland Sommarskog's article](http://www.sommarskog.se/dynamic_sql.html). In order to solve your problem is:

```
Dim strNew As String
Dim strOld As String

strSQL = "SELECT new.[Service Name], new.WBS, new.[Billing Code], new.[CPU Units], new.[VCPU Units], new.[Billing Status], new.[Bill To]" & _
"FROM " & strNew & " AS new LEFT JOIN " & strOld & " AS old ON new.[Service Name] = old.[Service Name]" & _
"WHERE old.[Service Name] Is Null;"
```

Let us know if this code works for you.

Comment: I'd say it is probably worth enclosing the variable table names in brackets too, e.g. `"FROM [" & strNew & "] AS new LEFT JOIN [" & strOld & "] AS old` - Given that the column names all contain spaces, it is reasonable to assume that the tables are named just as badly!

Comment: the spaces before FROM and WHERE are still missing ^^

Comment: @Paolo Although this is not bad advice, it is not the source of the error, because immediately before the `FROM` and `WHERE` there are object names in brackets (e.g. `new.[Bill To]FROM `), the query would still run. As an example the following still works correctly -------- `SELECT t.[name]FROM sys.tables AS t INNER JOIN sys.schemas AS s ON s.[schema_id] = t.[schema_id]WHERE 1 = 1;`

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. After trying your code Chancrovsky, I received an error message "3131" "Syntax error in FROM clause",

Comment: As Paolo said before, the space before FROM and WHERE are missing... i think this solve that problem: Dim strNew As String
Dim strOld As String

strSQL = "SELECT new.[Service Name], new.WBS, new.[Billing Code], new.[CPU Units], new.[VCPU Units], new.[Billing Status], new.[Bill To] " & _
"FROM " & strNew & " AS new LEFT JOIN " & strOld & " AS old ON new.[Service Name] = old.[Service Name] " & _
"WHERE old.[Service Name] Is Null;"

Comment: I updated the original post with the full code. Could I be making a mistake elsewhere?

Comment: when using dynamic sql, temporaritly print the value os strSQl to a message window so you can see where the query is building incorrectly.

Comment: Thanks everyone! I found my mistake was an unnecessary "=" sign in my original code.